# QuickControls2 Image does not stretch to full width of parent

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a simple QuickControls2 QML design where an image should stretch horizontally to fill the application window and maintain its aspect ratio. But when I run my program, the image doesn't scale/stretch.

*Is the problem that the image is smaller than the current window size and QT doesn't upscale/increase the size of the image? Is there a setting to make QT resize the image to fill the width regardless of image size?*

Can you let me know what is wrong and how I can fix it?

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Scroll")

    ColumnLayout {
        id: mainLayout
        anchors.fill: parent

        Image {
            id: imagePane
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: "placeholder.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `Image.PreserveAspectFit`, *image is scaled uniformly to fit without cropping* ,
Now since you are not filling Layout height, image can't scale beyond it's implicit height.

As your requirement is to *make QT resize the image to fill the **width** regardless of image size* means you accept to crop the image beyond the height limit, in which case you need to use:

`fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Scroll")

    ColumnLayout {
        id: mainLayout
        anchors.fill: parent

        Image {
            id: imagePane
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
            Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: "placeholder.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```